# multiple values in a dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have data in following form (saved in a list)

```
id, price, date, category
```

Now, I basically want to seperate items based on the category..
basically a dictionary where key is the category and rest of the stuff (id, price, data) are its values
I have already created a datastructure so lets a datastructre 'item' has the above four stated attributes (id, price, date, category)
So basically what i want is a dictionary in following form:

```
{1: [item_1,item_2....], 2:[item....]}
```

how do i do this..
Since there are many values in a single key hence i know that it will use defaultdict.. but still I am not able to get around this.
Thanks

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem. why the python dict don't works for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want something like this, assuming your current data is stored in the list `list_data`:

```
dict_data = defaultdict(list)
for item in list_data:
    dict_data[item.category].append(item)
```

If each item is a tuple instead of an object, use `item[3]` instead of `item.category`.

Answer (score 4):

```
output = defaultdict(list)
for item, cat in ((x[:-1], x[-1]) for x in data):
    output[cat].append(item)
```

or, without defaultdict:

```
output = {}
for item, cat in ((x[:-1], x[-1]) for x in data):
    output.setdefault(cat, []).append(item)
```

Example output:

```
>>> data = [
...     (1, 123, "somedate", "boy"),
...     (3, 435, "anotherdate", "boy"),
...     (23, 123, "moredate", "girl"),
... ]
>>> output = {}
>>> for item, cat in ((x[:-1], x[-1]) for x in data):
...     output.setdefault(cat, []).append(item)
... 
>>> print output
{'boy': [(1, 123, 'somedate'), (3, 435, 'anotherdate')], 'girl': [(23, 123, 'moredate')]}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to have a dictionary where each value is a list of items (id, price, date) and the key is the category.

Something along the lines of the following, where `d` is a dictionary, `c` is a category and `itm` is a tuple/item:

```
def insert(d, c, itm):
  if not c in d:
    d[c] = [itm]
  else:
    d[c].append(itm)
```